# Configure WRT-54GL to accept/forward connections from WAN

Tags: routing, port-forwarding

Is it possible to configure WRT-54GL (using only its own web interface and without modifying the firmware) so that it doesn't filter connections originating in WAN (this is done elsewhere on its uplink route)?

At the very least, I need to correctly configure IPP [631] port forwarding, which I have been unable to make work so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by placing the printer (which has a static IP address) into the DMZ.